# What are the benefits of using an online pass?

Tags: ps3, medal-of-honor

I bought a used copy of "Medal of Honor" for my PS3 the last days. As I opened the case there was a paper with a used online pass on it. Because I never owned a game which needed an online pass I started the multiplayer directly to check if I can play without buying a new one. After skipping the purchase of a new online pass (10€ btw) I could play online just like a normal game without such mechanics.

Due to [this EA-article](https://help.ea.com/article/online-pass-has-been-discontinued) I assumed that the online pass is no longer needed, but I can't find much more information.

> **Do I still need an Online Pass to play multiplayer games online?**
>
> For new EA titles, Online Pass will no longer be needed or included.  Additionally, we are in the process of eliminating Online Pass requirements from existing EA games.  This process will take several weeks.  For some games, the prompt to enter an Online Pass code will no longer appear; for others, you will still need to download and install an Online Pass, but they will be available free of charge from the Xbox LIVE Marketplace or PlayStation Store.

So my question is: Does Medal of Honor still need an online pass - the prompt to enter one is still there - and if so, what are the benefits of it? I could play without entering an online pass perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They changed it. Before you had to have an Online Pass to actually play online (there might be additional maps or classes playable with it, but I don't think so). As the pass should be free by now, just grab one to get rid of the prompt, in case it returns. Otherwise you could probably just ignore it.

Comment: As I wrote in my question the pass is not free at the moment. So you're just guessing do you?

Comment: I don't have the game on PS3, but it's very likely they just didn't update the shop yet (from what I know it's already free on the Xbox 360). Just wait till the price "drops" and grab it then. Till then just continue as you did so far.

Comment: I was able to activate the online pass which came with the used game. Since I don't know if the person I bought it from used the code, I'm not able to say if you can use already used codes. What I can say is, that you are able to download one free DLC with some maps, but it seems to be regular maps I was able to play before too. Therefore I would assume, that the online pass is 100% obsolete for medal of honor :)

Comment: Ah, interesting. The whole "just skip buying" shouldn't have been possible before, so not that surprising you don't see any difference there.